# Error when trying to use a constructor argument to initialise a property

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I work on a React/MobX project and I have a few classes like:

```
class UserStore {
    private canDeleteUsers = ['admin', 'moderator'].includes(this.role)

    constructor(private readonly role: string) { }
}
```

This did not cause any issues before I tried to migrate from CRACO to Vite with esbuild. Now everything runs fine, except the components that use this kind of pattern.

Any idea what caused it to break?

I'm targeting es2020 with both the esbuild config and the tsconfig.